# Select Distinct in Access? Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT (Min(Time_In) & " to " & Max(Time_Out)) AS [Week Of],
 Round((Sum(DATEDIFF("n", Time_In, Time_Out))/Count(DATEDIFF("n", Time_In, Time_Out))),2) AS [Avg Min of Jog]
FROM SomeTable
WHERE len(Time_In) > 0 AND len(Time_Out) > 0 
AND #01/01/2012# <= Time_In AND #12/31/2012# >= Time_In
GROUP BY DatePart('ww',Time_In);
```

Which picks out average times of a jog per week. I would also like to include a count how many times jogged per week, which I'm trying to do by counting the `jog_id` where `SomeTable` could have 5 entries for one `jog_id`.

I have tried:

```
SELECT (Min(Time_In) & " to " & Max(Time_Out)) AS [Week Of],
 Round((Sum(DATEDIFF("n", Time_In, Time_Out))/Count(DATEDIFF("n", Time_In, Time_Out))),2) AS [Avg Min of Jog],
 Count(distinct jog_id) AS [Num Jogs]
FROM SomeTable
WHERE len(Time_In) > 0 AND len(Time_Out) > 0 
AND #01/01/2012# <= Time_In AND #12/31/2012# >= Time_In
GROUP BY DatePart('ww',Time_In);
```

But this is giving me `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Count(distinct jog_id)'.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in Access without using a sub-query.
EX:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1);
```

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120805022223/http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx) is a detailed article on the topic:

Answer (score -1):

Access refuses to do good in nearly all circumstances, one of which is the support of the `Count(distinct x)`.