# Count the amount of unique IP adresses per category using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm teaching myself SQL and Access 2016 and now I am trying to do the following:

I have two tables, Table1 contains a list of URI's and categories and Table2 contain a list of URI's and IP's. Now I want to find out how many different IP's there are for each category in the list. Table 1's URI column is a subset of table 2's URI column.

```
Table 1:
URI | Categories

Table 2: 
URI | IP
```

So obviously I should do an inner join on both tables with the URI which gets me:

```
URI | Categories | IP
```

Now I need to find out per category how many different IP's there are. So for example if the category is "Boats" I want to know how many different IP's looked for that category. I believe this can be done with COUNT, but that only works for 1 single category right? I want to figure out the amount of different IP's each category has within a huge dataset (millions of rows), so not just for 1 category.

So basically what I'm looking to get is an output like this:

```
Category | # of unique IP's
___________________________
Boats    | 5
Insects  | 22
```

This question might be a bit simple and honestly I've been thinking about it / googling it for a full day now because the question seemed too simple to ask here, but I'm just stuck now.

Thanks in advance for the help!

P.S. If you need any more examples or explanation on what I'm trying to do just tell me and I'll get it! :)

**EDIT:**

I forgot to use DISTINCT.. So I just added that but now I get a syntax error in Access 2016? Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT Final_parsed_userlogs_access.Field1) AS CountOfField1, Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited.Field2
FROM Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited INNER JOIN Final_parsed_userlogs_access ON Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited.Field1 = Final_parsed_userlogs_access.Field4
GROUP BY Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited.Field2;
```

Small final edit: 
Apparently Access 2016 doesn't really work with Count distinct ([Select Distinct in Access? Syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530755/select-distinct-in-access-syntax-error)), but I don't understand how I should edit my own query to work with this fix?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Oh I haven't tried GROUP BY yet, thanks! I'm going to try playing around with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group it based on category, that should help!

Access-Engine does not support

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT....) FROM ...
```

You have to do it like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1)
```

Edit your query to:

```
    SELECT Count(T.Field1) AS CountOfField1, T.Field2
     FROM
    (SELECT Final_parsed_userlogs_access.Field1, Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited.Field2
    FROM Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited INNER JOIN Final_parsed_userlogs_access ON Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited.Field1 = Final_parsed_userlogs_access.Field4
    GROUP BY Final_category_list_all_uri_access_edited.Field2, Final_parsed_userlogs_access.Field1) as T
    GROUP BY T.Field2;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's it! I knew it was a simple question haha :') Thanks for the help

Comment: I actually made a small mistake, I forgot to use distinct so it counted all IP's instead of only the unique ones. I figured that just adding DISTINCT to the query would fix it, but when I do that Access 2016 says there is a syntax error.. Could you take a look at my query? :) I added it to the opening post for better readability!

Comment: I am editing my original answer to include change required for this as well.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I found that as well, but I do not understand how I should change my query to incorporate that fix? Because of the inner-join that's already in the FROM part?

Comment: Updated the answer to include your query. Not tested but should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you. That query gives the following error in Access 2016: "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect". Might be something with the "T"?

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you for the quick help, you're awesome :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thank you!